# Why is my child view not added to my scroll view?

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented a **Hamburger Menu** which gets called when the user taps a **BarButtonItem**.

When the user clicks an index of the menu a delegate method gets called and selects the correct row:

```
 func rowTapped(index: MenuIndex) {
        let vc1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1") as! VC!
        // lazy loading
        _ = vc1.self.view
        vc1.transitionToNew(index)
    }
```

And in my VC1 the ** transitionToNew** method gets called and selects the correct index: 
(Let´s assume that the user tapped index 1 which is associated to .a)

```
 func transitionToNew(_ index : MenuIndex) {
switch index {

case .a:
addSubviewToContainer(asChildViewController: childVC)
...
}
```

Now the **childVC** should be added into the **scrollView** of my **VC1**.

The **childVC** is instantiated lazy:

```
 private lazy var childVC: ChildVC = {
        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildVC") as! ChildVC
        return viewController
    }()
```

To add the **childVC** into the **scrollView** the **addSubViewToContainer** method gets called in the switch-case statement:

```
  private func addSubviewToContainer(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController)
    {

        viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        viewController.view.frame = scrollView.bounds
        addChildViewController(viewController)
        scrollView.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

I know that views gets instantiated **lazy** (sadly) so we have to input something like

```
_ = self.view
```

(although its a stupid hack) to instantiate the view which indeed shows me that my **scrollView** got instantiated (at least I think that because the preview in the debugger shows me the view)

Can someone tell me without seeing all of the code why my the **childVC** is not added or displayed (!?) in my **scrollView**?

I got the correct frame, the **scrollView** should be instantiated at the moment the user taps an index.

---

UPDATE

I also have some navigation buttons which the user can select:

```
@IBAction func navigateToChildVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
       addSubviewToContainer(asChildViewController: childVC)
       )
    }
```

It is calling the exact same method but here it is working.

Comment: complex hierarchy ... can you show visually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like with your implementation the scroll view cannot determine its content size, so setting it explicitly might fix your issue. Something in the lines of `scrollView.contentSize = scrollView.bounds.size` sets the content size so that it fills the scroll view in both dimensions - which might not be what you want for a scroll view, but that is a different discussion.

There is also no need to call addChildViewController when lazily creating the child view controller, it is enough to have it called in addSubviewToContainer.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I checked the frame in the debugger and it remains the same.

Comment: Which frame are you referring to? Also, can you please check which is the content size value for scrollView?

Comment: The frame of the scrollView. In my addSubview method: **viewController.view.frame = scrollView.bounds** This should give me the bounds of the scrollView.

Comment: The scroll view has a property called contentSize that will determine how much of its content - meaning its subviews - the scroll view will show. By default this property has value CGSizeZero. Even if the scroll view frame is correct and the childVC view frame is correct, if the scroll view content size is CGSizeZero, no scroll view content is displayed. Can you please check which is the content size value for your scroll view?

Comment: Printing out the content size of the scroll view when my addChildView method is called: **Content size of scrollView: (0.0, 0.0)**

Comment: Ok, and you tried setting the content size like this `scrollView.contentSize = scrollView.bounds.size`  in the addSubviewToContainer method and the child view controller is still not visible?

Comment: Yeah I tried this and it gives me different values depending on how I add my child: When I add my child view with the buttons the content size is (1024.0, 548) but when I add my child with my side menu it says  (1024.0, 595.0).. but the methods remain the same